# Consulta que alimenta grid e subgrid?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Como, por exemplo, gerar:

```
Autor 1
+-- Livro 1
+-- Livro 2

Autor 2
+-- Livro 3
+-- Livro 4
```

utilizando django-rest-framework? Isso em um consulta só?

Procurei encontrei com consulta e detalhes.. mas não exatamente assim.. :/

Answer (score 2):

Em primeiro lugar é bom levar em consideração que seus modelos estejam bem relacionados.
Para isso, se pergunte: consigo obter esse retorno utilizando apenas o ORM do Django? (como o amigo @Adir respondeu).

Se sim, quando você estiver definindo a serialização dos seus modelos, você deve definir a serialização dos relacionamentos entre eles.
No tutorial presente no site do django-rest-framework existe uma parte que ensina como este relacionamento pode ser feito: http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis#hyperlinking-our-api

Há também este capítulo na documentação, que abrange um pouco mais a utilização dos relacionamentos: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#hyperlinkedmodelserializer

A saber: o relacionamento entre recursos (resources, objectos) chama-se link (ou hyperlink, ou hypermedia) de acordo com o modelo de maturidade REST, proposto por Leonard Richardson

Answer (score 0):

Olá, bom acredito que você deva estar falando de fazer uma consulta SQL. Normalmente é complicado trazer esses dados organizados de uma consulta mas você pode fazer isso utilizando o ORM do Django, se você fez os relacionamentos corretos.

Provavelmente você deve recuperar os autores com algo assim

```
autores = Autores.objects.all()
```

Como disse se vc fez os relacionamentos corretos poderá recuperar todos os livros associados aos autores, algo assim

```
for autor in autores:
    autor.livros.all()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas a questão em pauta é a utilização do django-rest-framework